# Flutter: Как добавить несколько Keys в Card

Tags: flutter

Я создал ListView, а в нем card.
Надо чтобы в card были:
Дата,
Название,
Изображение,
(их вводит пользователь в Dialog)
При удалении одного элемента списка его название и изображение переходят в следующий, а из него в следующий и тд.

```
return Container(
            height: 150,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 10, right: 10),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5))
            ),
            key: Key(dates[index]),
            child: Card(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),),
              elevation: 10,
              color: cardColor,
              child:
                Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
```

Надо чтобы в `key: Key(dates[index])` были еще `names[index]` и `images[index]`

Comment: А что не так с наиболее очевидным решением `key: Key([dates[index], names[index], images[index]].join(';'))`?

Comment: Работает. Спасибо @yar85. Я не поместил все в квадратные скобки и не добавил `.join(';')`

Comment: Пожалуйста. Квадратные скобки это литеральная запись списка (объекта типа `List`), а `join` - метод списка, соединяющий строковые значения его элементов через указанный разделитель (в данном случае `';'`) - возвращает он, конечно же, строку.

Comment: Можно сделать проще (это ещё и работать будет быстрее): `key: Key("${names[index]}-${dates[index]}-${images[index]}")`